# Does Ruby have an equivalent of Python's twisted framework as a networking abstraction layer?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twisted

From my understanding, Python's twisted framework provides a higher-level abstraction for networking communications (?).

I am looking for a Ruby equivalent of twisted to use in a Rails application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [EventMachine](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/). It's not as extensive as Twisted but it's built around the same concepts of event-driven network programming.